# Project Layout with regards to Exrin and Databases

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, exrin

What is the preferred solution for Exrin project layout when adding a database?

The sample Tesla app had a separate project for the Services and another separate app for the Repository. With the removal of both of those projects in the latest template, it makes the most sense for it to go within the Logic project, but I'm curious if the author had a different preferred implementation.

Comment: Probably best to reach out to Adam directly. I'll point him to this question.

Comment: I've been in contact with him. He asked me to post these. He gets an email whenever an Exrin tagged question is posted. Thanks for looking out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tesla Sample project is designed for a very large app, and Service and Repository don't need to be separated out into a separate project, they can all be referenced directly in the logic app, as per this diagram.
[image]

This is the project setup, I now recommend for most projects.